# Avoid IP-based redirect and news feed

Tags: facebook-pages

**The problem:**

There are certain product pages (e.g.: film, videogames) that basing on your ip automatically redirect you to the locale of where you are living. This forces me to see only pages (and updates/feeds) in German, when I want the English ones.

- An example page: https://www.facebook.com/TotalWar
- If I click on that link I get redirected to: https://www.facebook.com/TotalWarDE (eventually with the option `?brand_redir=1` appended to the url)
- To see the English one I have to go here: https://www.facebook.com/TotalWar?brandloc=DISABLE (notice the option in the url)

No matter if I "like" the page on the redirected page or on the forced English page, I get the updates in my news feed from the German version :|

---

**The question(s):**

- As a user of Facebook, is it possible and if yes, how (eg. with Facebook options, GreaseMonkey scripts) to avoid geo-ip redirection from pages?
- Is it possible to receive the news feed in the desired language?

In the chat [jonsca](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/11175/jonsca) suggested me to have a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/115536/keeping-websites-from-knowing-where-i-live) from SU.SE:
I know that a proxy might do the job, but sincerely it would be my last resort (right after stop caring about those pages).

Comment: `?brandloc=DISABLE` doesn't appear to work anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately you can now simply click the three dots on the page in question and choose "Switch Region...".

[image: switch region]

Comment: At least with https://www.facebook.com/Fallout it works (I chose the UK version to be sure, since US is "default" which sounds like something that might one day revert, e.g. to a Swiss German version once provided...)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, in my opinion, would be to use a proxy server, preferably one with an app icon that allows you to connect/disconnect on demand. That way, you can decide which IP is represented to each page you browse. Simply select a server at the target country, and browse the content. The server will "think" you're in that country, and serve you local content.

Disconnect as needed, to get your local content.

Comment: I wouldn't call that easier than using the fortunately provided setting to switch, but of course this solution works for the internet in general (except for services that started blocking proxy-providers as well)

Answer (score 0):

Use the English pagename with `/ncr` after ("no country redirect"). Like this: `/pagename/ncr`. (The same as you do with Google).

Comment: I'm afraid that switch doesn't work (anymore, at least)